# f-string separating new line

Tags: split, slice, f-string

Does anyone know how to make this code into an f-string (if possible):

```
print(">>> Multi-line Comment", data, sep="\n")
```

So if there is 2 or more components in data it would print each in a new line. The above code works, its was just bugging me that I could do it for a single line, but couldn't for multiline.

For example: This works for a single line

```
print(f">>> Single-line Comment\n{data}")
```

This will work for if I know how many multilines there are, in this case 2:

```
print(f">>> Multi-line Comment\n{str.splitlines(data)[0]}\n{str.splitlines(data)[1]}")
```

Any ideas to make an f-string version more automated like `print(">>> Multi-line Comment", data, sep="\n")`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, f-strings don't like `\n`s so you have to work around it. You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
data = """Comment1
Comment2"""

x = data.splitlines()

print(f'[>>> Multi-line Comment",{chr(10)}{x[0]},{chr(10)}{x[1]}]')
```

or "fake" it:

```
nl = "\n"
print(f'[>>> Multi-line Comment",{nl}{x[0]},{nl}{x[1]}]')
```

In either case, the output should be:

```
[>>> Multi-line Comment",
Comment1,
Comment2]
```

Comment: I guess its just better to go without an f-string in this, since f-strings don't the same flexibility.

Comment: @tcraigmate You may be right at least in this case; but generally speaking, f-string are the best way, in my opinion, to inject variables into strings, so I tend to use them whenever possible.